# How to reshape c-style arrays

Tags: c, arrays

For example, I have 1 dimensional array of 20 elements that I want to reshape into a 4x5 array so, I can pass it to a function with a signature like the following . . . .

```
void func(type** inArray, int xDimension, int yDimension)
```

The data that I want to squeeze into `myArray` is of type `type*`. What do i need to do in order to reshape the array? I do not want to allocate a new array and use loops to fill the new array. Is there any way to cast the data in place?

The closest I have got is something like this . .

```
float one[20];
float* two[] = {one, one+5, one+10, one+15};
func( two, 4, 5);
```

Comment: [realloc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/realloc.html).

Comment: @moeCake in how far thats a solution? you should have notified that 4x5 is the same array size as 1x20. So in how far that reshapes the order?!

Comment: No, you can't cast it in place. You have to allocate an array of pointers somewhere, like in your example, and fill it. You could write a function to fill an existing array (which would have to have the correct size), or a function to `malloc()` and fill a new array.

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(type** myArray, int xDimension, int yDimension, type* oneDArray)
{
    int i,j,index=0;
    for(i=0;i<yDimension;i++)
    {
         for(j=0;j<xDimension;j++)
         {
             myArray[i][j]= oneDArray[index++];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just fills an existing 2D array with the contents of a 1D array. I do not want to generate a 2nd array and copy the data, rather re-index the existing data

Comment: and how do you want to re-index it? it will suitable if you give example through a virtual matrix....

Comment: @zeeshanmughal You dont have to do all these loops just `memmove(&myArray[0[0],oneDArray,xDimension*yDimension*sizeof(type));`